# Run ProgressBar only while thread runs

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Im trying to increment a ProgressBar as long as the thread is running a method called getAll() with:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(getAll));
thread.Start();
pbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
if (thread.IsAlive)
    pbStatus.Value++;
else 
    pbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

My ProgressBar xaml:

```
<ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="10" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

The ProgressBar appears if I start `getAll` but does not hide if the method is finished.

I've tried to use for hiding the progressbar setting `thread.isAlive` to `false` but seems to make no difference.

My problem is, that I don't know how long `getAll` runs and how much I get back to do some "progressing", so I thought it is a good idea to check if the thread is still running and simply increment my `ProgressBar` as long as it runs?

Comment: Did you try using `BackgroundWorker` ?  Also, why are you not using `async Task` instead of directly using `Thread`  ?

Comment: Hi Manoj, Im using `async Task`. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use below solution.  I would strongly recommend to use `Task` over `Thread`.

Thread is a lower-level concept: if you're directly starting a thread, you know it will be a separate thread, rather than executing on the thread pool etc.

Task is more than just an abstraction of "where to run some code" though - it's really just "the promise of a result in the future".

So in general, it is recommended to use higher level abstraction wherever possible.

```
private async void OnSomeEvent(..)
{
    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;  // maybe show it
    var result = await GetAll();
    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false; // Maybe hide it

    // TODO: Do something with result
}


private async Task<Results> GetAll()
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to use BackgroundWorker? here is your code with BackgroundWorker

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

    pbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    getAll();
    //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    //{
    //    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
    //    Thread.Sleep(100);
    //}
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

}

void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Your ProgressBar xaml:

```
<ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="10" Visibility="Hidden" />
```